# What is a right way to work with reducer in Redux?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, redux

I am building an app, sort of dictionary app. In my app a user can add, update and delete a word. Something happened and now my update function does not work. I don't understand why. When I click an update button an error appears in the console. Your hints and suggestions are appreciated.

[image]

**Word update API**

```
// @route  Put api/words/:id
// @desc   Update a word by id
// @access Private
router.put(
  '/:id',
  passport.authenticate('jwt', { session: false }),
  (req, res) => {
    const { errors, isValid } = validateWordInput(req.body);

    // Check validation
    if (!isValid) {
      // Return any errors
      return res.status(400).json(errors);
    }

    Profile.findOne({ user: req.user.id }).then(profile => {
      Word.findById(req.params.id).then(word => {
        // Check for word owner
        if (word.user.toString() !== req.user.id) {
          return res.status(401).json({ notauthorized: 'User not authorized' });
        }

        const wordID = req.params.id;
        const wordInput = req.body;

        // Update
        Word.findByIdAndUpdate(
          { _id: wordID },
          { $set: wordInput },
          { returnOriginal: false },
          (err, word) => {
            if (err) {
              console.log(err);
            }
          }
        )
          .then(word => {
            res.json(word);
          })
          .catch(err =>
            res
              .status(404)
              .json({ wordcannotbeupdated: 'word cannot be updated' })
          );
      });
    });
  }
);
```

**Word actions**

```
export const updateWord = (id, updatedWord, history) => dispatch => {
  axios
    .put(`/api/words/${id}`, updatedWord)
    .then(res => {
      dispatch({
        type: UPDATE_WORD,
        payload: res.data
      });
      history.push('/my-words');
    })
    .catch(err =>
      dispatch({
        type: UPDATE_WORD,
        payload: ''
      })
    );
};
```

**Word reducer**

```
import {
  GET_WORDS_BY_USER,
  ADD_WORD,
  UPDATE_WORD,
  GET_WORD_BY_ID,
  DELETE_WORD,
  SEARCH_WORD
} from '../actions/types';

const initialState = {
  words: [],
  word: {},
  loading: false
};

export default function(state = initialState, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case ADD_WORD:
      return {
        ...state,
        words: [action.payload, ...state.words]
      };
    case GET_WORDS_BY_USER:
      return {
        ...state,
        words: action.payload
      };
    case GET_WORD_BY_ID:
      return {
        ...state,
        word: action.payload
      };
    case UPDATE_WORD:
      return {
        ...state,
        words: action.payload
      };
    case SEARCH_WORD:
      return {
        ...state,
        words: action.payload
      };
    case DELETE_WORD:
      return {
        ...state,
        words: state.words.filter(word => word._id !== action.payload)
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

**Edit Word React component**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Link, withRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
import TextFieldGroup from '../common/TextFieldGroup';
import SelectListGroup from '../common/SelectListGroup';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { getWordByID, updateWord } from '../../actions/wordActions';
import isEmpty from '../../validation/is-empty';
import {
  lexisOptions,
  grammarOptions,
  partOfSpeechOptions,
  styleOptions,
  originOptions,
  sphereOptions
} from './options';

class EditWord extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      ugrWordCyr: '',
      rusTranslation: '',
      example: '',
      exampleTranslation: '',
      origin: '',
      sphere: '',
      see: '',
      lexis: '',
      grammar: '',
      partOfSpeech: '',
      style: '',
      errors: {}
    };
    this.onChange = this.onChange.bind(this);
    this.onSubmit = this.onSubmit.bind(this);
    this.onCheck = this.onCheck.bind(this);
  }

  componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    if (nextProps.errors) {
      this.setState({ errors: nextProps.errors });
    }

    if (nextProps.words.word[0]) {
      nextProps.words.word.map(word => {
        word.ugrWordCyr = !isEmpty(word.ugrWordCyr) ? word.ugrWordCyr : '';
        word.rusTranslation = !isEmpty(word.rusTranslation)
          ? word.rusTranslation
          : '';
        word.rusTranslation = !isEmpty(word.rusTranslation)
          ? word.rusTranslation
          : '';
        word.example = !isEmpty(word.example) ? word.example : '';
        word.exampleTranslation = !isEmpty(word.exampleTranslation)
          ? word.exampleTranslation
          : '';
        word.origin = !isEmpty(word.origin) ? word.origin : '';
        word.sphere = !isEmpty(word.sphere) ? word.sphere : '';
        word.see = !isEmpty(word.see) ? word.see : {};
        word.lexis = !isEmpty(word.lexis) ? word.lexis : {};
        word.grammar = !isEmpty(word.grammar) ? word.grammar : {};
        word.see = !isEmpty(word.see) ? word.see : {};
        word.style = !isEmpty(word.style) ? word.style : {};

        this.setState({
          ugrWordCyr: word.ugrWordCyr,
          rusTranslation: word.rusTranslation,
          example: word.example,
          exampleTranslation: word.exampleTranslation,
          origin: word.origin,
          sphere: word.sphere,
          style: word.style,
          lexis: word.lexis,
          grammar: word.grammar,
          see: word.see,
          partOfSpeech: word.partOfSpeech
        });
      });
    }
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.getWordByID(this.props.match.params.id);
  }

  onSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    const wordData = {
      ugrWordCyr: this.state.ugrWordCyr,
      rusTranslation: this.state.rusTranslation,
      example: this.state.example,
      exampleTranslation: this.state.exampleTranslation,
      origin: this.state.origin,
      sphere: this.state.sphere,
      see: this.state.see,
      lexis: this.state.lexis,
      grammar: this.state.grammar,
      partOfSpeech: this.state.partOfSpeech,
      style: this.state.style
    };
    let id = this.props.match.params.id;
    // Change a function to update
    this.props.updateWord(id, wordData, this.props.history);
  }

  onChange(e) {
    this.setState({ [e.target.name]: e.target.value });
  }

  onCheck(e) {
    this.setState({
      current: !this.state.current
    });
  }
  render() {
    const { errors } = this.state;

    return (
      <div className="add-word">
        <div className="container">
          <div className="row">
            <div className="col-md-8 m-auto">
              <Link to="/my-words" className="btn btn-light">
                Go Back
              </Link>
              <h1 className="display-4 text-center">Edit Word</h1>
              <form onSubmit={this.onSubmit}>
                <TextFieldGroup
                  placeholder="Бала"
                  info="Введите слово на уйгурском"
                  name="ugrWordCyr"
                  value={this.state.ugrWordCyr}
                  onChange={this.onChange}
                  error={errors.ugrWordCyr}
                />
                <TextFieldGroup
                  placeholder="Ребенок"
                  info="Введите слово на русском"
                  name="rusTranslation"
                  value={this.state.rusTranslation}
                  onChange={this.onChange}
                  error={errors.rusTranslation}
                />
                <div className="form-check mb-form">
                  <input
                    type="checkbox"
                    className="form-check-input"
                    name="see"
                    value={this.state.see}
                    onChange={this.onCheck}
                    id="see"
                  />
                  <label htmlFor="see">Смотри</label>
                </div>
                <TextFieldGroup
                  placeholder=""
                  info="Введите пример предложения на уйгурском"
                  name="example"
                  value={this.state.example}
                  onChange={this.onChange}
                  error={errors.example}
                />
                <TextFieldGroup
                  placeholder=""
                  info="Введите перевод примерного предложения на русском"
                  name="exampleTranslation"
                  value={this.state.exampleTranslation}
                  onChange={this.onChange}
                  error={errors.exampleTranslation}
                />
                <h6>Происхождение слова</h6>
                <SelectListGroup
                  placeholder="Арабское"
                  name="origin"
                  value={this.state.origin}
                  onChange={this.onChange}
                  error={errors.origin}
                  options={originOptions}
                />
                <h6>Сфера употребления слова</h6>
                <SelectListGroup
                  placeholder="Физика"
                  name="sphere"
                  value={this.state.sphere}
                  onChange={this.onChange}
                  error={errors.sphere}
                  options={sphereOptions}
                />
                <h6>Лексика слова</h6>
                <SelectListGroup
                  placeholder="лексика"
                  name="lexis"
                  value={this.state.lexis}
                  onChange={this.onChange}
                  error={errors.lexis}
                  options={lexisOptions}
                />
                <h6>Стиль слова</h6>
                <SelectListGroup
                  placeholder="стиль"
                  name="style"
                  value={this.state.style}
                  onChange={this.onChange}
                  error={errors.style}
                  options={styleOptions}
                />
                <h6>Часть речи</h6>
                <SelectListGroup
                  placeholder=""
                  name="partOfSpeech"
                  value={this.state.partOfSpeech}
                  onChange={this.onChange}
                  error={errors.partOfSpeech}
                  options={partOfSpeechOptions}
                />
                <h6>Грамматика слова</h6>
                <SelectListGroup
                  placeholder="грамматика"
                  name="grammar"
                  value={this.state.grammar}
                  onChange={this.onChange}
                  error={errors.grammar}
                  options={grammarOptions}
                />
                <input
                  type="submit"
                  value="submit"
                  className="btn btn-info btn-block mt-4"
                />
              </form>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

EditWord.propTypes = {
  getWordByID: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  errors: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
  updateWord: PropTypes.func.isRequired
};

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  errors: state.errors,
  words: state.words
});

export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  { getWordByID, updateWord }
)(withRouter(EditWord));
```

Comment: Just clearing things up, whenever you click on the button it gives you an error? Even without text?

Comment: Actually, it is not supposed to update a word if input field is empty, so there should always be something.

Comment: hmm I see, so based on the code you posted I dont see what could be causing the issue. How does your Word Model look?

Answer (score 0):

> axios
>       .put(`/api/words/${id}`, updatedWord)

if you are using relative api endpoint then it will be going to request to

```
<react-server-host:port(which is 3000 in your case)>/api/words/${id}
```

and i am assuming you are running your backend service on another port than 3000 . Thats why it is giving error **404 not found**
So when you are requesting api, write absolute endpoint

```
<backend-server-host:port>/api/words/${id}
```